# Create array in foreach, key to be the first value in loop

Tags: php

I have some filters:

```
$filters = array('rooms-4-5', 'city-london-berlin-paris');
```

and I wanna create a array like this:

```
array(
     'rooms' => array('4', '5'),
     'city'  => array('london', 'berlin', 'paris')
);
```

I tried:

```
    foreach($filters as $filter):
        $filter = explode('-', $filter);
        $data[$filter[0]] = array();
        array_shift($filter);
        foreach($filter as $value):
            //here I am stuck ...
        endforeach;
    endforeach;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have been fairly close, except for that fact that you already have the array elements in `$filter` and you only needed to remove the first variable (by using `array_shift()`) and insert it.

The thing is that [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) (link to documentation) returns the removed value so you can store that in the array and use it for the key. And the array after shifting is ready to be used.

Here's the full result:

```
<?php
$filters = array('rooms-4-5', 'city-london-berlin-paris');
$out = array();
foreach($filters as $filter) {
    $filter_exploded = explode('-',$filter);
    $val = array_shift($filter_exploded); // remove first element, add it to the variable
    $out[$val] = $filter_exploded;
}
var_dump($out);
```

Comment: Yeah you are right, I was in a mind loop and can't figured out. Maybe some sleep will help. System will allow me to accept as answer in 5 minutes. Thank you.

Comment: You can't. However you build these arrays, you'll have to change the dash with something else. So either the dash of the city name or the dash that separates all the elements. If you can build it like `city_london_berlin_paris`, it would probably be better since no city will have an underscore :)